# Android Basics with Compose Codelab out of date?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am wanting to learn Jetpack Compose so I am working through the course on Android Basics with Compose at https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-compose/course

I follow the directions in "Create your first Android App" but I get the follwoing error message:
"Some Kotlin libraries attached to this project were compiled with a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update Kotlin plugin." The issue seems to be in the ManifestActivity.kt file at line "import.androidx.activity.compose.setContent" setContent is not recognized.

Build output is as follows:

failed
We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34

This Android Gradle plugin (7.0.4) was tested up to compileSdk = 31

This warning can be suppressed by adding
android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34
:app:mergeDebugResources
values.xml
C:\Users\MarkRussell.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f74c47f20864d032a62d32a63dbab692\transformed\material-1.9.0\res\values\values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall'

I have, in a previous attempt to solve this error, upgraded the AGP to version 8.02,but that created dozens of other issues.

I am using the current stable build of Android Studio which is much more recent than that forseen in the lesson, and I am using JDK 20.

I have, in a previous attempt to solve this error, upgraded the AGP to version 8.02,but that created dozens of other issues.